# Reference to member function in C++/CX

Tags: c++, xaml, c++-cx

I'm trying to make a timer that calls a function at a preset interval. This is the code I have so far.

```
void MainPage::startTimer()
{
    DispatcherTimer^ refreshTimer = ref new DispatcherTimer;
    refreshTimer->Tick += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Platform::Object^>(this, &MainPage::refreshFunc);
    TimeSpan t;
    t.Duration = 500;
    refreshTimer->Interval = t;
    refreshTimer->Start();
}

void MainPage::refreshFunc(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to compile I get an error that says:

```
invalid delegate initializer -- function does not match the delegate type
```

The error points to the second parameter of the EventHandler in this line (line 4 above):

```
refreshTimer->Tick += ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Platform::Object^>(this, &MainPage::refreshFunc);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using C++/CX and compiling with VS2015 Community

Comment: Make it `EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs^>` so it matches the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second parameter's type to `Platform::Object^`:

```
void MainPage::refreshFunc(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e)
```